# How can I change background color using an if statement in PHP using CSS

Tags: php, css, sql

I'm looking to change the color of a cell in a table based on returns from a mySQL database.

```
song_order |   encore    
1          |     0             
2          |     0       
3          |     0       
4          |     0       
5          |     0       
6          |     0      
7          |     0       
8          |     1      
9          |     1       
10         |     1        
11         |     2       
12         |     2
```

I'm echoing out the song_id cell but not the encore cell...
How can I use the values in the encore cell to change the background of the song_id cell only?

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($show))
  {   

  echo "<tr>";  

   echo "<td style='padding: 10px; width:5px;'>" . $row['song_order'] ." </td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
```

Would it be something like this? But how do I add these if values to 'song order'?
I just don't know if this is right or how it needs to be modified...

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($show))
```

{if ($row['encore'] == "0") 
    $tdClass = 'mainset';

else if ($row['encore'] == "1") 
    $tdClass = 'encore1';

else if ($row['encore'] == "2") 
    $tdClass = 'encore2';

echo "";

echo "" . $row['song_order'] ." ";
      }
      echo "";

```
CSS
 .mainset {
    background-color:transparent;
 }
 .encore1 {
    background-color:pink;
 }
 .encore2 {
    background-color:blue;
 }
```

Am I on the right track, can someone help me with this code? Am I missing something and this already works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now put the class like

```
echo "<tr>";  
    echo "<td style='padding: 10px; width:5px;' class='<?php echo $tdClass;?>'>" . $row['song_order'] ." </td>";
 echo "</tr>";
```

And makesure that you put the right classes for the right css

As per you comment try like this.Yor are echoing $tdClass in an echo which causes you conflict

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($show)) {
     if ($row['encore'] == "0") 
         $tdClass = 'mainset'; 
     else if ($row['encore'] == "1") 
         $tdClass = 'encore1'; 
     else if ($row['encore'] == "2") 
          $tdClass = 'encore2'; 
     echo "<tr>"; 
         echo "<td style='padding: 10px; width:5px;' class='".$tdClass."'>" . $row['song_order'] ." </td>";
     echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: doesn't seem to be working... should tdClass be $tdClass that doesn't work either not sure what I maybe doing wrong. I did a few combinations nothing worked

Comment: Have you echoed the $tdClass value after initialization..??

Comment: With the <?php ?>  the whole column disappears 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($show))
{if ($row['encore'] == "0") 
    $tdClass = 'mainset';

 else if ($row['encore'] == "1") 
    $tdClass = 'encore1';

 else if ($row['encore'] == "2") 
    $tdClass = 'encore2';
  
    
echo "<tr>";  
  
  echo "<td style='padding: 10px; width:5px;'  class='echo $tdClass;'>" . $row['song_order'] ." </td>";

this shows the column again but doesn't change the background

Comment: THANK YOU Gautam!!! putting that operator (.) in there helped... I think that's what it's called correct? I'm just learning

Answer (score 0):

css classes or ids can't start with numbers

change:

```
.1encore {
    background-color:pink;
 }
 .2encore {
    background-color:blue;
 }
```

to

```
 .encore1 {
    background-color:pink;
 }
 .encore2 {
    background-color:blue;
 }
```

Comment: thanks for the tip... I guess I know just enough to be dangerous but missed that